# how to know if a third-party app you open from your Android app is closed/exited

Tags: android, android-activity

**Some background information:**

my Android app has four classes
:MainActivity,MyGcmListenerService,RegistrationIntentService, and RingCall.
 If I presses on a button connected to my RPI3, then the RPI3 send a message titled "ringdoor" to my android app and  method "onMessageReceived" in MyGcmListenerService takes care of the received message by  starting the actvity "RingCall" that  shows a blue ring call screen in this way:

```
  if (message.equals("ringdoor")){
           sendNotification(title, "The home doorbell rang");
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,RingCall.class); 
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(intent);
```

The call screen has two options : "Accept" or "Decline". if I click on "Accept", then I go to the "Foscam" webcam app. the lines of code that does this are shown below:

```
answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerButton);
answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent OpenFoscamApp= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.foscam.foscam");
                startActivityForResult(OpenFoscamApp, 1); // CHANGED
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**My question:**

When I open the "foscam" company webcam app from my android app by clicking on "Accept" and  I decide to exit the app after that,  how can I can **know**/**check**  from my app that the webcam app was exited.  are there any lines of that can do a check for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using startActivityForResult, when the activity you launch is finished it will return via onActivityResult.  If the user doesn't end the activity but just hits home or opens some other app, there is no notification.